# Routing a kafka message to be published on a different channel spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-integration, spring-cloud

I have three outbound channels "sendData", "sendDataA", "sendDataB" pointing to three topics test-topic, test-topic-1, test-topic-2 respectively. I wanted to know if its possible route messages on channel sendData to either sendDataA or sendDataB? Basically when sendData.send() method is called, I want the message to be published on the topic corresponding to sendDataA(test-topic-1) or sendDataB(test-topic-2).

Here's what I tried:

```
@Configuration
public class OutboundChannels {

    @Autowired
    private RoundRobinRouter roundRobinRouter;

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow routeRoundRobin() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(getSendData())
                .route(roundRobinRouter, "route",
                        r -> r.channelMapping("sendDataA",
                                        "sendDataA")
                                .channelMapping("sendDataB",
                                        "sendDataB"))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean(name = "sendData")
    public MessageChannel getSendData() {
        return MessageChannels.direct()
                .get();
    }

    @Bean(name = "sendDataA")
    public MessageChannel getSendDataA() {
        return MessageChannels.direct()
                .get();
    }

    @Bean(name = "sendDataB")
    public MessageChannel getSendDataB() {
        return MessageChannels.direct()
                .get();
    }
}
```

The round robin class(currently there's no logic here it always returns sendDataA):

```
@Component
class RoundRobinRouter {
    public String route(Object payload) {
        return "sendDataA";
    }
}
```

topic binding in application.yml:

```
    stream:
      bindings:
        sendData:
          destination: test-topic
          binder: kafka
        sendDataOne:
          destination: test-topic-1
          binder: kafka
        sendDataTwo:
          destination: test-topic-2
          binder: kafka
```

However, this isn't working. The message is not routed to sendDataA but instead published on sendData's topic.

Any pointers on a fix for my approach or any other approach to achieve the same is appreciated.

Comment: `>on sendData's topic.` What is that? `sendData` is just a simple channel in that configuration - do you have other consumers on it? If so, messages will be distributed to its subscribers in round robin fashion.

Comment: @GaryRussell Since I am routing messages to a different channel, so whenever I do sendData.send() it should publish to test-topic. But since there's a router I expected the message to be routed to a different channel based on what the router returns. Since the router is hardcoded to return "sendDataA", I expected all messages sent using sendData.send() channel to be routed to "sendDataA" channel i.e., published to test-topic-1. But the message is still published on test-topic.

Comment: That is not a surprise: you have a `sendData` binding configuration. So, whenever you call `sendData.send()` the message may land on the topic or on the mentioned router. The `DirectChannel` comes with a round-robin dispatching strategy by default. See Gary's answer.

Comment: @ArtemBilan wow, I wasn't aware that the Direct channel comes with a round-robin dispatching strategy. How can I always send it to the router?

Comment: Why do you provide then binding for that `sendData`? See more info in docs about `DirectChannel`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#channel-implementations-directchannel

Comment: The binding is the topic where I want to publish the message. But, we plan to run some tests where the message should be published on a different topic. So, I am trying to see how to reroute a message to be published on one channel to instead publish on a different channel through the router.

Answer (score 1):

With that configuration, you have two subscribers, the binding and the router.

The first message will (probably) go to the binding, the second will go to the router, the third to the binding, etc.

If you want it to go to both places, change `sendData` to a `publishSubscribe` channel.

Comment: Is there a way to make the message always go the router instead of round-robin like topic->router->topic?

Comment: Only by removing the binding definition for `sendData` (or set its `autoStartup` to `false`).